# Problems accessing Django model fields from model before migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm moving the field `some_field` from `Model_A` to a new `Model_B`, with a OneToOne relationship. Before deleting this field in `Model_A`, I want to copy the value from (the historical) `Model_A` to the newly created `Model_B`. The problem is that I cannot retrieve the field at migration time, since `Model_A` doesn't any longer contain `some_field`.

This is the error message I get when I try running my custom migration:

```
AttributeError: 'Model_A' object has no attribute 'some_field'
```

Models before changes:

```
class Model_A:
    some_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    some_other_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Models after changes:

```
class Model_A:
    some_other_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Model_B:
    model_a = models.OneToOneField(Model_A, related_name='extension')
    some_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
        # This is where I try to get the "historical" Model_A
        Model_A = apps2.get_model("my_app", "Model_A")

        # And this is where I intend to copy the some_field values
        for model_A_instance in Model_A.objects.all():
            b = Model_B(model_a=model_A_instance)
            # b gets created correctly, but the following step fails
            b.some_field = modelA_instance.some_field
            b.save()

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Model_B',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('some_field', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('model_a', models.OneToOneField(related_name='extension', to='my_app.Model_A')),
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),

        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func),

        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='model_a',
            name='some_field',
        ),
    ]
```

I'm pretty much aware that I somehow have to get hold of a "historical" representation of `Model_A` (= the one currently in the database), but I thought that was what the `apps2.get_model("my_app", "Model_A")` part was for.

Any input on how to accomplish this? Or should I maybe split the migration into two, where the first one creates `Model_B` + copies the `some_field` values and the second one deletes the some_field field from `Model_A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to have historical representation of `Model_A` and it's pretty easy to retrieve it. Thats what `apps` passed into your function called by `RunPython` migration is for, so why are you using some `apps2` insdead of apps here? Also, you should get your `Model_B` from same `apps` instance as `Model_A` is from. Your migration should look like that:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
        # This is where I try to get the "historical" Model_A
        # here is change - using apps passed into forwards_func by RunPython instead of apps2
        Model_A = apps.get_model("my_app", "Model_A")
        Model_B = apps.get_model("my_app", "Model_B")

        # And this is where I intend to copy the some_field values
        for model_A_instance in Model_A.objects.all():
            b = Model_B(model_a=model_A_instance)
            b.some_field = modelA_instance.some_field
            b.save()

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Model_B',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('some_field', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('model_a', models.OneToOneField(related_name='extension', to='my_app.Model_A')),
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),

        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func),

        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='model_a',
            name='some_field',
        ),
    ]
```

Why are you using `apps2` anyway? And what it is?

Comment: It seems I have forgotten to change back from one of me previous attempts with this import:
from django.apps import apps as apps2

Unfortunately, removing that import and running apps.get_model() doesn't solve the problem. It gives me the folllowing error instead:
ValueError: Cannot assign "<Model_A: Model_A object>": "Model_B.model_a" must be a "Model_A" instance.

Comment: Your `Model_B` should be fetched using same `apps` as `Model_A`, see updated answer.

Comment: GwynBleidD, you deserve a medal!

Everything went smoothly when I fetched the new models the same way as Model_A. Somehow I thought it would be OK to mix them. Obviously, I was wrong! :)

Comment: You should __never__ import models from `models.py` or other sources in migrations. Always rely on `apps` passed into your custom migration functions.